# Verify Domain with external Service

Tags: custom-domain, external-services

I am refering to this article
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_mgmt_verify_external.htm&type=5 to verify google external services with my community. But I dont see the verify option itself. Does any one face the same issue.

Comment: Have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288388/push-notifications-from-google-drive-to-salesforce , might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Salesforce has updated the Domains page to remove the 'verify' link, as Apple has removed the need for domain verification when setting up Sign-in with Apple as per article: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev1c0e25352
2. The Verify link was used for Sign In with only Apple but not for any other services.
3. Any integrations of Apple pay/google with Custom domains are currently not in the salesforce release roadmap.
4. The link [Push notifications from Google drive to Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288388/push-notifications-from-google-drive-to-salesforce) suggested on comments provides an idea on the approach that can be taken in the context of push notifications involving a third party and might help